# Push Notifications doesn't always trigger methods in iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm receiving notifications using this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadComments" object:nil];
}
```

That trigger this method:

```
- (void) reloadComments:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSDictionary* dict = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"commentNotification"];
    NSString* video_id = [[[dict objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"custom"] objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSData* cData = [video_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *errorJson2;
    NSMutableDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:cData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson2];

    int number = [[commentsDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [response objectForKey:@"video_id"]]] intValue];

    number += 1;
    [commentsDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [response objectForKey:@"video_id"]]];
}
```

I'm parsing the result and incrementing the **number**. This works correctly when i launch the app, in my device, through XCode. If i send 5 push notifications the **number** is 5.

If i do the same procedure without launching the app through XCode, the **number** is not correctly incremented.

Anyone has any experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: hey @bruno how can u receive notification on xcode explain ur question clearly !

Comment: @bruno I made some formatting upgrades to your code to make it more clear. Please look at it here: http://pastie.org/9469762

Comment: try to log ur count and notice ur console on orgnizer , is your didreceivenotification method hitting or not !

Comment: @AnilPrasad Everything works fine when i log. The problem is when i disconnect the app from XCode.

Comment: never faced this kind of strange issue@bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the completionHandler below and it started working.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [self parsePushNotifications:userInfo];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```